# My wampserver seems to be having issues dealing with external JS and CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, wamp

Ok, I guess this is technically 2 separate issues, but they seem similar enough that it seems worthwhile to ask them in one go (I'm really new at all this, and none of the other questions seem to have relevant answers).

For whatever reason, whenever I try running this test bingo web game I made via localhost on my wampserver (out of the box config afaik), the external javascript will not run at all, and while most of the css file works well enough, I can't seem to make the table borders show up. Although, as was making this post, the js file seems to be working fine, but I still can't seem to get table borders to show up (not even inlining seems to fix the problem). Could this be a php problem? I'm new to wamp and php is probably the area that I'm most clueless about.

```js
var phase1 = []
var phase2 = []
   
for (i = 0; i < 37; i++){
        phase1[i] = i + 1
}

for (i = 0; i < 25; i++){
    var potVal = Math.floor(Math.random()*(phase1.length))
    phase2[i] = phase1[potVal]
    phase1.splice(potVal,1)
}

for (i = 0; i < phase2.length; i++){
    var count = i + 1
    var elem = count.toString()
    document.getElementById(count).innerHTML = phase2[i]
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: steelblue;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

table{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(223, 165, 6);
    padding: 1%;
    width: 40%;
    height:80%;
    margin: auto;
    
}
table, th, td{
    border: 10px black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Demo Bingo Game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="stylegrrl.css" />
    <link rel="script" type="text/javascript" href="boople.js">
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Bingo Card<br>Test Game</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th id="1"></th>
            <th id="2"></th>
            <th id="3"></th>
            <th id="4"></th>
            <th id="5"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="6"></th>
            <th id="7"></th>
            <th id="8"></th>
            <th id="9"></th>
            <th id="10"></th>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="11"></th>
            <th id="12"></th>
            <th id="13"></th>
            <th id="14"></th>
            <th id="15"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="16"></th>
            <th id="17"></th>
            <th id="18"></th>
            <th id="19"></th>
            <th id="20"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="21"></th>
            <th id="22"></th>
            <th id="23"></th>
            <th id="24"></th>
            <th id="25"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm assuming `boople.js` is the local JS file that you included?

Comment: yes, that was the name of the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function test(){  
    var phase1 = []
    var phase2 = []
       
    for (i = 0; i < 37; i++){
            phase1[i] = i + 1
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        var potVal = Math.floor(Math.random()*(phase1.length))
        phase2[i] = phase1[potVal]
        phase1.splice(potVal,1)
    }

    for (i = 0; i < phase2.length; i++){
        var count = i + 1
        var elem = count.toString()
        document.getElementById(count).innerHTML = phase2[i]
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Demo Bingo Game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: steelblue;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        h1{
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        table{
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgb(223, 165, 6);
            padding: 1%;
            width: 40%;
            height:80%;
            margin: auto;
            
        }
        table, th, td{
            border: 10px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bingo Card<br>Test Game</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th id="1"></th>
            <th id="2"></th>
            <th id="3"></th>
            <th id="4"></th>
            <th id="5"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="6"></th>
            <th id="7"></th>
            <th id="8"></th>
            <th id="9"></th>
            <th id="10"></th>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="11"></th>
            <th id="12"></th>
            <th id="13"></th>
            <th id="14"></th>
            <th id="15"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="16"></th>
            <th id="17"></th>
            <th id="18"></th>
            <th id="19"></th>
            <th id="20"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="21"></th>
            <th id="22"></th>
            <th id="23"></th>
            <th id="24"></th>
            <th id="25"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        test();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think your code working fine. You need to mention the border style property as well for that table.

```
table, th, td{
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mv3gbx9f/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much, fixed the border issue right up. js file still won't load from wamp though.

edit: to provide more context, the code works just fine whenever I have it on the page, right after the table, but moving it to an external file causes it to go completely awol.

Comment: I think there is a <!DOCTYPE html> issue. Can you please remove the first line of your html and use the above one... And please let me know  if its worked or not...

Comment: Its worked in my end. I think there is a issue with your wamp server. Please check server config.

Comment: changed the <!DOCTYPE> issue, js file still isn't loading. Just checked in dev mode on chrome, it's not loading the js file. is there any particular config files I should look at?

Comment: Can you please use the updated answer. I have added a function in js file and calls it in your html file. 
If you are using external JS file you need to create a js function and use it in your html file.

Comment: Sorry, missed some parentheses, Everything is working fine now, thank you so much for your help, can't begin to describe how relieved I am.

Comment: Ok, thats nice to hear from you.